# use pandas to access elements in scalar format

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with some of the following rows:-

```
restaurantName        cuisine      totalRating   delivery
Bindia Indian Bistro  indian          4.0         Yes
Bhoj Indian Cuisine   indian          4.5         Yes
Indian Roti House     indian          4.0         Yes
Utsav                 indian          4.0         Yes
```

let's call it df3. Now writing following works in python console :-

```
df3[df3.restaurantName == 'Bindia Indian Bistro'].totalRating.item()
```

but when i try to do the same using a file read as follows:-

```
for line in f1:
    restName = line.strip('\n')
    print(restName) # to check if restaurant name is read fine
    overallToRest = df3[df3.restaurantName == restName].totalRating.item()
```

it gives following error message:-

```
 Bindia Indian Bistro
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-cdb8b6170a65>", line 18, in prepare_final_file
    overallToRest = df3.loc[df3['restaurantName'] == restName]['totalRating'].item()

  File "C:\Users\myName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 814, in item
    return self.values.item()

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

I tried to search it on Stack Overflow but could not find any answer relevant to my problem. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in column `restaurantName` are duplicates, so filtering return not only one value, but more.

So is possible select only one value to scalar, e.g. first by `[0]` and then check if not `empty` `Series` in `if-else`:

```
overallToRest = df3.loc[df3.restaurantName == restName, 'totalRating']

overallToRest = 'no match' if overallToRest.empty else overallToRest.iat[0]
```

Another solution is [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) first:

```
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates('restaurantName')
overallToRest = df3.loc[df3.restaurantName == restName, 'totalRating']

overallToRest = 'no match' if overallToRest.empty else overallToRest.item()
```

---

Sample:

```
print (df3)
         restaurantName cuisine  totalRating delivery
0  Bindia Indian Bistro  indian          4.0      Yes
1  Bindia Indian Bistro  indian          4.5      Yes
2     Indian Roti House  indian          4.0      Yes
3                 Utsav  indian          4.0      Yes



restName = 'Bindia Indian Bistro'

overallToRest = df3.loc[df3.restaurantName == restName, 'totalRating']
print (overallToRest)
0    4.0
1    4.5
Name: totalRating, dtype: object

print (overallToRest.item())
```

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

```
overallToRest = 'no match' if overallToRest.empty else overallToRest.item()
print (overallToRest)
4.0
```

---

```
restName = 'Bindia Indian Bistro'

df3 = df3.drop_duplicates('restaurantName')
print (df3)
        restaurantName cuisine  totalRating delivery
0  Bindia Indian Bistro  indian          4.0      Yes
2     Indian Roti House  indian          4.0      Yes
3                 Utsav  indian          4.0      Yes

overallToRest = df3.loc[df3.restaurantName == restName, 'totalRating']
print (overallToRest)
0    4.0
Name: totalRating, dtype: float64

overallToRest = 'no match' if overallToRest.empty else overallToRest.item()
print (overallToRest)
4.0
```

Comment: i tried to implement this solution but now it gives following error:-
`File "<ipython-input-15-af8453130207>", line 24, in prepare_final_file
      print(overallToRest.values[0])
      IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 `

I think it is because there may be some restaurants in file that are not there in the dataframe. To correct this I applied try, exception block to skip such restaurants, but still it gives this same error.